# Putting expiry time on parse object

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am saving a parse object using these lines:

```
 ParseObject x=new ParseObject("names");
 po.put("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
 po.saveInBackground();
```

Is there any way to put an expiry time on this object after which the object will automatically be deleted from parse.As I am getting a scenario where if this object is not deleted I have to put an extra ParseQuery for deleting the object.

Comment: Exactly why do you want that? Your approach might be wrong.

Comment: May be but if there is any way to do it?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Why do you want to remove the object? Is it calling itself and throwing exceptions?

Comment: I want to optimize the size of the data so I thought that after a certain time the uploaded files could be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about deleting objects from Parse to increase performance unless you're dealing with thousands of objects.

The best solution in my eyes is to schedule a background job that runs one time per day and deletes any objects that have a `shouldBeDeleted` property set to `true` or something like that.

Then to mark an object for deletion, you would just have to set the `shouldBeDeleted` to true.

Comment: I thought a lot about your Idea and tried to implement.I think you were right.It works good.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule an AsyncTask to do that, anyway looks a bit strange. Maybe you should consider another strategy.

Comment: It would cost one more query to delete the object.Is there any way so that parse object can delete itself after given time interval?

Comment: "one more query to delete the object", you cant remove object using a query. You remove stored value using a query.

Comment: Sorry I dont know so much about parse so I am confused so much

Comment: Your task only has to run po.put("username", null);. Anyway, I don't understand why you need to do that, but there is no query there, just setting a value to null.